# Bitmap of Android WebView is blank

Tags: android, webview, bitmap, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of an Android WebView and the result is a blank image. I know there are lots of questions about this but everyone seems to have resolved it in a way or another and I can't.

I tried:

- the `draw()` method
- the `capturePicture()` method, now deprecated.

The WebView renders **properly**, but when I share the picture it's blank.

This is my screenshot class:

```
public class Screenshot {
    private final View view;

    /** Create snapshots based on the view and its children. */
    public Screenshot(View root) {
        this.view = root;
    }

    /** Create snapshot handler that captures the root of the whole activity. */
    public Screenshot(Activity activity) {
        final View contentView = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        this.view = contentView.getRootView();
    }

    /** Take a snapshot of the view. */
    public Bitmap snap() {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.view.getWidth(),
                this.view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }

    public Uri snapAndSave(File cacheDir) {
        File outputFile;
        try {
            outputFile = File.createTempFile("myfile", ".png", cacheDir);
            if (savePic(snap(), outputFile)) {
                return Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static boolean savePic(Bitmap b, File outputFile) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            if (null != fos) {
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            }
            return true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: /** Create snapshot handler that captures the root of the whole activity. */ What is: `android.R.id.content` ? Your code is ok using `R.id.webView1`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Can confirm that this code works for both taking snap of webview and activity.

Comment: Right, can I ask you what Android version and target SDK? I've got 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 and target 19 and it's not working. Thanks.

Comment: What made that you did not tell that from start? I used 4.1.2.

Comment: On 4.4.2 it also runs ok here.

Comment: Found a peculiarity. If i scroll to the bottom af a page and take a snap of the webview the picture is from the top of the page although it was not visible. Taking a snap of the activity the webview contents is as was seen. Any idea?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not quite. I was using Cordova and found a plugin that worked fine most of time: https://github.com/josemando/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Screenshot

Answer (score 2):

WebView can be capture with the `getDrawingCache()` method:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromWebView(WebView webView) {
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webview.getDrawingCache());
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```